# nest multiplex API : "connection" vs "group connection"?

Tags: nest-api, multiplexing

Having read through the Nest Multiplex API guide here:

https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/multiplex-overview

There are several mentions of something called a "multiplex group connection".

Verbatim, from the doc:

> Each multiplex connection should have 10-20 user connections. As you build more multiplex connections, you can gather them into a multiplex group connection, which should be limited to <300 connections.

They show very clearly what a multiplex connection is (basically just invoked with a curl command.) But there is no mention of what a group connection is, or any other details.

Comment: the cURL command is just showing an example of establishing a multiplexed connection, the actual protocol being used is Rest Streaming.

Comment: yes, the protocol is rest streaming, but having read those documents, there's no mention of what a multiplex/group connection is there either.

Comment: Ah I see what you're talking about, we'll fix up these docs to add a but about multiplexing. What it is essentially is a way to use one open socket to listen to multiple users. In Rest Streaming you can only use 1 token (user) per socket, what multiplex does is allows multiple tokens (users) per socket.

Comment: @urman Could you explain how to actually do this.  I understand how to do it for 20 users, but then it goes on about grouping to connections, however I cannot find anything on how to actually do this

Comment: sorry for the delay! The 20 number is mostly arbitrary. The idea is 20 is a good number of tokens to start a pool. Pools max out at 1000 tokens per stream, but are most efficient from a platform perspective at 20-200 tokens. Docs should be re-worded to be clearer.